# Different methods of accessing Azure storage

Tags: azure, storage, data-access

Is there any other method for accessing Azure storage other than using key and account name?

Comment: There is an alternative. You can access your files by using the Azure portal. There are third party tools as well, however they will also require the credentials you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of - and I haven't heard of any plans to change this anytime soon either.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide your key and account name when using the APIs.  You can access your publicly accessible BLOBs from Blob Storage without providing any info though.